# stopPropagate() is not working in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I have a user sign up page with username and password choice fields, I'm providing validation and availability asynchronously using event listeners,

```
    //username
$("#username" ).bind('blur',function(e){
//ajax call 
if (e.target == e.currentTarget) {
       e.stopPropagation();               
       e.preventDefault();
}
    return false;      
       });


//userpassword
$("#userpassword" ).bind('blur',function(e){
//ajax call 
 if (e.target == e.currentTarget) {
       e.stopPropagation();               
       e.preventDefault();
       }
       return false;
 });
```

However on blur (ring) the child password field the ajax call on the username field is also activated, I suspect that this is a bubbling issue but somehow `stopPropagate()` is not working.

//adding the mark up

```
            <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form1" id="form1">
 <ul>
            <li>
              <input name="user[name]" type="text" id="username" accesskey="u" value="" maxlength="15" autocomplete="off" class="username" /></li>
<li><input name="user[password]" type="text" id="userpassword" accesskey="p" value=""  autocomplete="off" class="userpassword" /></li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Comment: I doubt that that is your problem, because your event handler is *also* returning `false`.  Returning `false` from a handler has exactly the same effect as calling both "stopPropagation" and "preventDefault" - therefore your handlers will *always* stop propagation.

Comment: Maybe you could add some of the HTML around those form elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Description of [`stopPropagation`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) from jQuery API...

> Prevents the event from bubbling up
>   the DOM tree, preventing any parent
>   handlers from being notified of the
>   event.

A textbox cannot be the parent of another textbox, so this is not going to work.

Comment: hi, so what could account for the bubbling effect?
If it's not a parent/child affair then they are adjacent right?
any ideas?
thanks

Comment: I don't believe there is any bubbling.  It just doesn't make sense for `blur` to bubble.

Comment: fixed it, did a rewrite of the code entirely in jQuery and well it just worked, wasn't a bubbling problem afterall
thanks